# WSO2 ESB JSON to XML conversion

Tags: xml, json, paypal, paypal-sandbox, wso2-esb

Here the incoming type is JSON, I couldn’t find any way to specify the incoming message format in payload factory mediator. What is wrong in payload factory mediation? Below is my uri-template.

```
<template name="createPayment" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
      <sequence class="sequence">
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>
                {
                  "intent":"sale",
                  "payer":{
                    "payment_method":"credit_card",
                    "funding_instruments":[
                      {
                        "credit_card":{
                          "number":"4417119669820331",
                          "type":"visa",
                          "expire_month":"11",
                          "expire_year":"2018",
                          "cvv2":"874",
                          "first_name":"Joe",
                          "last_name":"Shopper",
                          "billing_address":{
                            "line1":"52 N Main ST",
                            "city":"Johnstown",
                            "country_code":"US",
                            "postal_code":"43210",
                            "state":"OH"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "transactions":[
                    {
                      "amount":{
                        "total":"7.47",
                        "currency":"USD",
                        "details":{
                          "subtotal":"7.41",
                          "tax":"0.03",
                          "shipping":"0.03"
                        }
                      },
                      "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
                    }
                  ]
                }
            </format>
            <args/>
        </payloadFactory>
        <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json" />
        <call>
          <endpoint>
            <!-- <http method="post" uri-template="{uri.var.paypalUrl}/v1/payments/payment"/> -->
            <http method="post" uri-template="https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment"/>
          </endpoint>
        </call>
      </sequence>
    </template>
```

curl client Post with the JSON data:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Authorization:Bearer EMxItHE7Zl4cMdkvMg-f7c63GQgYZU8FjyPWKQlpsqQP" \
-d '{
----
}
```

The response error is:

```
{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"payer","issue":"Required field missing"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"fc119def7e08d"}
```

Comment: If your curl request was querying paypal direct with the same payload and you got the same response, looks like your paypal endpoint is not finding what it is looking for. Could you capture the request between the ESB and the paypal endpoint by using the tcpmon tool? (This should be bundled with the ESB). Also, I hope those are fake CC details :)

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution. By default, JSON stream formatter and builder options are disabled. So need to enable them, uncomment the following lines in <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/
conf/axis2/axis2.xml:

<!--messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONStreamFormatter"/-->
<!--messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONStreamBuilder"/-->